# Like, comment, share missing in Like-Box Widget?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-iframe, facebook-likebox, facebook-widgets

It's awful that this thing is called "Like"-Box and there is no way to like, comment or share on an actual wallpost shown in the activity feed!

Is there a way to customize the Like-Box core so that these three little items are shown?

Would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The only customization options are those found on the [documentation page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/).  You could build your own though using the Facebook graph API to pull a pages feed down and add like and share buttons.